# How to select master page from database asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I saved in my database some master pages as a part of my school work.
I want to render selected master page from my database on page load event, because I am using get method in my form.
How can I render master page on page load event?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is it web forms, right?

Comment: yes @ricardofranca

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OnLoad Event is to late to change your MasterPage at runtime. You can change it on the Pre_Init event:

```
    protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
     Page.MasterPageFile = "~/myMaster.master";
}
```

**Edit:**

Based on your comment, here a sample from Microsoft:

[specifying the masterpage programaticly](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/older-versions-getting-started/master-pages/specifying-the-master-page-programmatically-cs)

Comment: I know, but I can't know which master page to render because this information is on database.

Comment: you mean how to get information from database?

Comment: no, i mean how to set master page from the database @jackjop